# attendance forms from multiple teachers

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I am a music school manager, and I am facing  a problem that im trying to solve  with google forms.

**Problem**: Teachers do not fills attendance forms since the current system is very heavy and hard to operate. Most of the teachers are old and do not work well with computers. **BUT - THEY HAVE SMARTPHONES**.

I want to solve it by letting them fill out a simple form (they will have a link to this form via an email, so they: open the mail - click on link and get to form - fill it - submit - voila).

There are 12 teachers with ~150 students. Of course each one of the teachers needs to view his students only.

I tried using a code to autopopulate the names from a spreadsheet, it worked well until I duplicated a working set from one teacher to another. At that point the new form aotupopulated the names from the previous teacher, and I couldnt seem to fix it.

**the desired solution** - a simple form, with all the names of the students of the teacher shown in multiple checkboxes, so the teacher will check each one of the students who showed to to class, and submit. 
All the information should be stored on the same spreadsheet with different tabs, for each one of the teachers.

important note - the classes are 1 on 1  - guitar piano etc. however I dont need to fill the form 1 by 1 , the teacher can fill all of the students who showed at a day at once - and submit.

any help will be deeply appreciated!

E

Comment: You can use Add-ons for this.  From your Google Form, you can search for Add-ons.  There are also groups that specialize in solutions for schools.  If you really want to program this yourself, and you want to use Stack Overflow as a resource, then you need to learn what is expected when asking a question.  A good question includes some code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example of an attendance recorder

Code.gs

```
function onOpen()
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Tools')
    .addItem('Take Roll', 'getRollList')
    .addToUi();
}
```

Attendance.gs

```
function getRollList()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('Roll');
  var rng=sht.getRange(1,1,sht.getLastRow(),4);
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var s='';
  for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    var dataA={};
    for(var j=0;j<4;j++){dataA[rngA[0][j]]=rngA[i][j];}//StudentID,Last,First,Middle
    s+='<div  id="' + dataA.StudentID + '" ><input type="checkbox" name="roll" value="' + dataA.StudentID + '" /><strong>' + dataA.StudentID + '</strong> - ' + dataA.Last + ', ' + dataA.First + dataA.Middle + '</div>';
  }
   s+='<br /><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" /><input type="button" value="Record Attendance" onClick="getCheckedBoxes(\'roll\');" />';
   s+='</body></html>';

   var html=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('attendance').setWidth(400).setHeight(450);
   html.append(s);
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, 'Attendance Sheet');
}

function recordAttendance(present)
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('Roll');
  var rng=sht.getRange(1,1,sht.getLastRow(),sht.getLastColumn()+1);
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    if(i==0)
    {
      rngA[i][rngA[0].length-1]=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MM/dd");
    }
    else
    {
      if(present.indexOf(rngA[i][0])>-1)
      {
        rngA[i][rngA[0].length-1]='X';
      }
      else
      {
        rngA[i][rngA[0].length-1]='0';
      }      
    }
  }
  rng.setValues(rngA);
  return true;
}

function displayMessage(msg)
{
  var output=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('attendance')
  output.append(msg + '<br />' + 'Date: ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy"));
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(output, 'Attendance has been Recorded')
}
```

attendance.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
function getCheckedBoxes(chkboxName) {
  var checkboxes=document.getElementsByName(chkboxName);
  var present = [];
  var absent=[];
  for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) 
  {
     if (checkboxes[i].checked) 
     {
        present.push(checkboxes[i].value);
     }
  }
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(setResponse)
    .recordAttendance(present);
}

function setResponse()
{
  google.script.run.displayMessage('Attendance Recorded')
}
console.log('script here');
</script>
   </head>  
  <body>
```

My Spreadsheet before taking roll

[image]

My Spreadsheet after taking roll

[image]

The attendance recording form:

[image]

The final message dialog

[image]